# Error to connect database in Eclipse JDBC ODBC,

Tags: eclipse, jdbc, netbeans, odbc

I'm looking for resolve problem with eclipse, im trying to connect to MySQL via ODBC im using java 1.7, and the same code in NetBeans, and Eclipse,

```
Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:Gtable","root","");
```

In NetBeans it works fine but in Eclipse returns

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at testdb2.testd.main(testd.java:11)
```

How can i fix it ?

I added it to build path
[image]

it did not help

---

Im using this now,

```
 try {
              Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
              System.out.println("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver found");
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException cnfe) {
              System.out.println("Error: sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver not found");
            }
```

And it returns jdbcodbc not found, where can i get that ?

Comment: You have added the required libraries for the UCanAccess JDBC driver, but then you are trying to use the JDBC-ODBC Bridge. They are two completely different ways of connecting to an Access database. If you really want to use UCanAccess (which does not use ODBC at all) then your connection URL should begin with `jdbc:ucanaccess://`. (Also, get rid of the `Class.forName` statement completely; it is not needed.)

Comment: i cant use ucanaccess, because i have to use ODBC, this is my quest, jdbc driver works now, but JdbcOdbcDriver dont. And i don know where i can get this jar

Comment: What does `System.getProperty("java.version")` return when you run your application?

Comment: hmm its weird but, returns 1.8 but im using 1.7, now i dont know how can i change it

Comment: In Eclipse, right-click the project in Package Explorer and choose "Properties". In the "Run/Debug" pane, edit the current launch configuration and go to the "JRE" tab. There you can pick another JRE (if one is available).

Comment: yee it works now :) thx a lot, i just installed 1.7 jre and added new enviroment, ufff

Comment: Instead of using ODBC to connect to a MySQL database, I strongly suggest you use the MySQL Connector/J JDBC driver.

Answer (score 2):

The issue with the Eclipse project was that it was actually running under Java 8, so the JDBC-ODBC Bridge was not available. Changing the run configuration to use a Java 7 JRE solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this correctly, add a folder called lib to your current project. 
Download the jar for the driver and drag this jar from your file explorer in your lib folder in eclipse.
After this, right click your project folder -> java build path, look for the libraries tab and click add jars.
Browse to your jar in the lib folder and click OK. After this click ok again.
This should work :)

Try this:

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
```

If this doesn't work, you probably gave the wrong path.
Try searching in your referenced libraries in the package explorer view.
Just expand the jar and look for driver.class.
If this is to much work, your could try searching with shift + ctrl + r.
adjust your filter to your needs.
You need to search for the path of driver.class

I also suggest you not to use root and give it a strong password

Comment: i tried to do that, i edited my post, i pasted build path

Comment: Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");  this works now, when i find and add jdbc.jar. Now i need to find and download odbc.jar probubly

Comment: search for the mysql jdbc driver. If you added this jar to your libs, this would be enough.

Comment: Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"); works now but this :  Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver"); still doesnt work, where can i get jar with this ?

Answer (score -1):

You should open project property (alt+Enter), open menu "Deploy Assembly", and set libraries folder, where you have jdbc driver.
Something like this:
[image]